# "Speak out against the fraud" - meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

> He suggested that we speak out against the election fraud.

What is the exact meaning of this sentence to natives:

1. that he asked us to say that there was no fraud in the election (so we say *there was no fraud*),
2. that he asked us to publicly talk about the election fraud (so we say *there was fraud*)

Comment: The phrase "the election fraud" only makes sense if you believe that there *has* been election fraud.

Comment: Note that the wording is such as to convey a prejudice regarding the actual occurrence (and cause) of the "fraud".  This is a classical case of using words to twist perceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This native hears that there was election fraud, and we are encouraged to speak against it.  Otherwise, for your meaning #1, we would be exhorted about the fraudulent claim of election fraud.

Comment: So we are encouraged to publicly say that there was election fraud. Right?
But is there something like "speaking out in favor of the election fraud". What would that mean?

Comment: Speaking out in favor of fraud can be done, but you would be declaring yourself a hypocrite and above the law.  (That doesn't mean people don't do it ...)

Answer (score 0):

*Speak out against* means to denounce or publicly criticize.  It never means "to deny the existence of".